# expected unqualified-id before 'namespace' error in working with boost spirit qi

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I am writing a c++ application with several complex structs and

I want to read a string and fill those structs by data provided in that text.

But for easier understanding and debugging, i've wrote easy program with same problem.

This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE  30
#define BOOST_PHOENIX_USE_V2_OVER_V3

#include <boost/spirit/home/phoenix/bind/bind_function.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>


namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

using qi::double_;
using qi::char_;
using qi::lexeme;
using qi::int_;
using qi::lit;
using qi::_1;
using ascii::space;
using phoenix::ref;
using qi::parser;


class Test 
{
    // Class fields
    std::string test_str;
    public:

        Test(std::string& sample_str)
        {
            test_str = sample_str;
        }

        struct fruit
        {
            std::string name;
            std::string color;
        };
        BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
            (
             fruit,
             (std::string, name)
             (std::string, color)
            );      
        struct person
        {
            std::string name;
            int age;
        };

        BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
            (
             person,
             (std::string, name)
             (int, age)
            );

        void received_person(person& p)
        {
            std::cout << p.name << " with age"<< p.age<< " has been seen!"<<std::endl;
        }
        void received_fruit(fruit& f)
        {
            std::cout << f.name<<" is "<<f.color<<std::endl;
        }

        template <typename Iterator>
            struct MyGrammar : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, void()>
        {
            MyGrammar() : MyGrammar::base_type(my_item)
            {
                my_item = *(fruit[ boost::phoenix::bind(&received_fruit, boost::spirit::_1 )]
                        |
                        _person[ boost::phoenix::bind(&received_person, boost::spirit::_1 )]
                        );

                 _person = qi::lit('(') >> *(qi::char_ - ',') >> ',' >> qi::int_ >> ')';
                _fruit = qi::lit('[') >> *(qi::char_ - ',') >> ',' >> *(qi::char_) >> ']';


            }
            qi::rule<Iterator, void()> my_item;
            qi::rule<Iterator, person()> _person;
            qi::rule<Iterator, fruit()> _fruit;
        };

        void run()
        {
            typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator;
            MyGrammar <std::string::const_iterator> my_grammar;
            std::string::const_iterator begin = test_str.begin();
            std::string::const_iterator end = test_str.end();
            bool result_ = qi::parse(begin, end, my_grammar) && begin == end;
        }
};


int main()
{
    std::string input("(jane, 23000)(david, 19)(mary, 30)[yello,100][green, 60.6][red, 30.5]");

    Test test(input);
    test.run();

    return 0;
}
```

g++ compiles this code and generates this error:

```
expected unqualified-id before 'namespace'
```

i know this code can be written without using class, but i want to use class in main project.
many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which line has an error?

Comment: line 44 generate this error! before BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT

Comment: The above does not have line numbers.

Comment: At line which defines BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT for fruit structure

Comment: My guess is that the BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT macro is doing something that does not allow it as a child of a class.  I would recommend researching what exactly BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT is doing.  Also, you might try moving the declaration outside of the class to see if that helps (this may not fit in with your intended design, but it may help diagnostically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Addressing the issues, first:

1. BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT needs to be at global namespace

   > *The macro should be used at global scope, and struct_name should be the fully namespace qualified name of the struct to be adapted.* [**[documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html)**]
2. you needed a skipper to allow for whitespace as in your sample input

   - this also implies you need `qi::phrase_parse` to supply a skipper
   - this also implies that `begin == end` was redundant (because `qi::parse` always consumes the whole input on success AFAIR)
   - this also implies you need `qi::lexeme` to control when you expect whitespace as part of the parsed content
3. you needed the callbacks to be `static`
4. you needed to modify the `_fruit` rule to read **until** the closing `]`

With these taken care of, your code works: See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9aa9f661cd46763f)**

#### Bonus material

Just in case you didn't know, you don't have to jump through all these fusion/phoenix hoops if you don't want. You'd usually parse into datastructures first, and then process there.

See this demonstrated **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f75877edcab7e25e)** too.

E.g., data structures:

```
namespace ast {
    struct fruit {
        std::string name;
        std::string color;
    };
    struct person {
        std::string name;
        int age;
    };

    typedef boost::variant<fruit, person> record;
    typedef std::vector<record> records;

    // for our demo output:
    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, fruit const& f);
    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, person const& p);
}
```

And the code that handles it (note improved status reporting):

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    std::string const input("(jane, 23000)(david, 19)(mary, 30)[yello,100][green, 60.6][red, 30.5]");

    MyGrammar <It> my_grammar;

    It begin(input.begin()), end(input.end());

    ast::records data;
    if (qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, my_grammar, qi::space, data))
    {
        std::cout << "Parse success\n";
        for (auto const& record : data)
            std::cout << record << "\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (begin != end)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(begin, end) << "'\n";
}
```

Now, the clincher is, the grammar becamse simpler too (no more phoenix; I assumed that names/colors should not contain `,`,`]` or `)`):

```
    _text   = qi::lexeme [ *~qi::char_(",)]") ];
    _person = qi::lit('(') >> _text >> ',' >> qi::int_ >> ')';
    _fruit  = qi::lit('[') >> _text >> ',' >> _text >> ']';

    _start  = *(_fruit | _person);
```

Here's the **[full code listing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f75877edcab7e25e)**:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace ast {
    struct fruit {
        std::string name;
        std::string color;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, fruit const& f) { return os << f.name << " is " << f.color; }
    };
    struct person {
        std::string name;
        int age;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, person const& p) { return os << p.name << " with age" << p.age << " has been seen!"; }
    };

    typedef boost::variant<fruit, person> record;
    typedef std::vector<record> records;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::fruit,
    (std::string, name)
    (std::string, color))

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::person,
    (std::string, name)
    (int, age))

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct MyGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, ast::records(), Skipper>
{
    MyGrammar() : MyGrammar::base_type(_start)
    {
        _text   = qi::lexeme [ *~qi::char_(",)]") ];
        _person = qi::lit('(') >> _text >> ',' >> qi::int_ >> ')';
        _fruit  = qi::lit('[') >> _text >> ',' >> _text >> ']';

        _start  = *(_fruit | _person);
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, ast::records(), Skipper> _start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ast::person(),  Skipper> _person;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ast::fruit(),   Skipper> _fruit;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()>           _text;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    std::string const input("(jane, 23000)(david, 19)(mary, 30)[yello,100][green, 60.6][red, 30.5]");

    MyGrammar <It> my_grammar;

    It begin(input.begin()), end(input.end());

    ast::records data;
    if (qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, my_grammar, qi::space, data))
    {
        std::cout << "Parse success\n";
        for (auto& r : data)
            std::cout << r << "\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (begin != end)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(begin, end) << "'\n";
}
```

Comment: Ah. I just added a phoenix-less version. Note how my version weighs 72 lines of code (40 lines less), when it arguably does more. **PS** (why were you using Phoenix V2 over V3? I don't recommend this due to lack of support/bugs). See http://boost-spirit.com/home/2013/12/13/farewell-phoenix-2/

Comment: I've used phoneix v2 over v3 for using phoenix bind.

Comment: v3 has bind too, and it has many more features and fewer bugs